# What is a mild detergent?

Tags: cleaning

I recently obtained a dehydrator, and the instructions say for cleaning you have to:

> "Simply soak the trays in warm water with a mild detergent for several
>   minutes"

Can someone please define the term "mild detergent"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd presume they just mean dish soap and not some more powerful cleanser.  With regard to additives, etc. I guess whatever you are okay with normally should be okay.  Obviously you have to rinse the trays thoroughly to get the soap off.

I've had a few dehydrators and there is nothing special about the plastic trays.  I doubt they are dishwasher safe but I've never put that to the test (I suspect it would not work that well anyway).  The trays can be pesky to clean if you've used a marinade. The best thing I've found for this is a small, soft circular brush.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but if anyone comes across it wondering. The answer is that mild detergents are dish soap like Dawn, Palmolive, etc.

Comment: To the contrary, my mother-in-law's CPAP technician told her Dawn is too harsh to clean her hoses and nozzles with and she should use Joy instead so, even among dish soaps, there are levels of mildness. I always prefer Dawn because it gets everything out while Joy sometimes misses a spot.